# Bypassing the salary computation ODOO

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

Is there any way of bypassing the salary computation, because we already have a software to compute salary for employees and i do not want to change that.

Comment: This doesn’t explain anything, You need to explain whole process to understand what actually you want o bypass.

Comment: We guys figured it out....one more question, can we create a custom time-sheet module with our respected wanted fields.

Comment: Great , Yeah defiantly you can do create custom module with field that you want. Here's Guide: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html

Comment: thanks, but can we make this timesheet module work the way odoo timesheet works?

Comment: Yeah, once you opt for customizations, you are in driving seat so you can change business processes the way you want. It could be potentially complex implementation but possible.

Comment: ok...thanks....how do we print reports for the custom module.....i couldnt figure out any code for that.